# Store into a list multiple lists

Tags: r, length, list

I have list of 50 lists of pairs of SpatialLinesDataFrames. That means I have something like:

```
[[1]]

     [,1]    [,2]    [,3] 
[1,] spldf1  spldf3  spldf5        
[2,] spldf2  spldf4  spldf6   

[[2]]

     [,1]    [,2]    [,3] 
[1,] spldf1  spldf3  spldf5        
[2,] spldf2  spldf4  spldf6       

.
.
.
[[50]]

     [,1]    [,2]    [,3] 
[1,] spldf1  spldf3  spldf5        
[2,] spldf2  spldf4  spldf6
```

I want a list of 50 elements of pairs with the length of every pair. I did:

```
for(i in 1:50){
  for(j in 1:3){ 
      lengthpair[[i]]=sum(length(pairs[[i]][[1,j]]),length(pairs[[i]][[2,j]]))
  } 
}
```

`lengthpair` is a list to store the sum of length of pairs every time.
`pairs` is the list with the pairs of SpatialLineDataFrames.

From this all I get is the sum of the length of last pair, of last run of my loop. What can I change to my code to do it?

Comment: What is `class(pairs[[1]])`?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly clear what you're asking, but here's an attempt:

```
lapply(pairs, function(pr) apply(pr, 2, function(jj) sum(sapply(jj, length))))
```

Is that what you wanted?